# Jenkins failure cause message not part of Gerrit trigger response

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, gerrit-trigger

I have some Jenkins pipelines, and on failure they send a -1 Verified response back to the gerrit review that triggered it. I also have the Build Failure Analyzer plugin, which I used to scan the console log for failure causes when the job fails.

On an older Jenkins installation (that I didn't manage), I used to get this failure cause back in the -1 Verified response in the gerrit review if one was found. I don't have that working at the moment.

Does anyone know if there is some gerrit trigger configuration needed, or another plugin to use to enable this?